# How to fix "is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause" in sql

Tags: sql, sql-server, database

```sql
    select PRES_NAME,min(PR_AGE),SPOUSE_NAME,SP_AGE 
    from PRES_MARRIAGE
    group by PRES_NAME
```

why my code isn't working?

Comment: You should explain what you want the query to do.  The error seems quite self-explanatory.

Answer (score 2):

Because you have to include all non aggregate columns in your `GROUP BY` clause. Like this:

```
    SELECT PRES_NAME,min(PR_AGE),SPOUSE_NAME,SP_AGE 
    from PRES_MARRIAGE
    group by PRES_NAME,SPOUSE_NAME,SP_AGE
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want the first marriage for each pres, then one method is:

```
select pm.*
from pres_marriage pm
where pm.age = (select min(pm2.age)
                from pres_marriage pm2
                where pm2.pres_name = pm.pres_name
               );
```